# How to configure Quarkus to go beyond 20 Mysql connections?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, quarkus

I am unable to go beyond 20 Mysql connections, while working with Quarkus.

Here is the content of the application.properties file that is used:

```
quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
quarkus.datasource.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
quarkus.datasource.username =root
quarkus.datasource.password =
quarkus.http.test-port=38030
quarkus.http.port=38030
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.initial-size=50
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=100
```

I am using the file **persistence.xml** below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="GenerateWorkerPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <description>Hibernate test case template Persistence Unit</description>

        <properties>
            <!-- intentionally using worse case so that we can optimise for this -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>

            <!-- Connection specific -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="1000"/>

            <!-- Tuning and debugging -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>

            <!--
                Optimistically create the tables;
                will cause background errors being logged if they already exist,
                but is practical to retain existing data across runs (or create as needed) 
                <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
                -->
            <!-- drop-and-create create-only -->


            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the following annotation:

```
@PersistenceUnit (unitName = "GenerateWorkerPU")
EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

These save me from having to modify in depth the code coming from wildfly 13.

The code is working fine but beyond 20 Mysql connections , I get the following error from the log:

```
2020-05-17 19:11:14,791 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-2) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2020-05-17 19:11:14,791 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-2) Sorry, acquisition timeout!
2020-05-17 19:11:14,798 SEVERE [DAO.GenerateCertStatusDaoV2] (executor-thread-2) null: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1542)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1581)
        at DAO2.GenerateCertStatusDaoV2.findByName(GenerateCertStatusDaoV2.java:53)
        at threading2.SignatureProducerCV1.call(SignatureProducerCV1.java:87)
        at threading2.SignatureProducerCV1.call(SignatureProducerCV1.java:33)
        at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeThreadContext$ContextualCallable.call(SmallRyeThreadContext.java:117)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningCallable.call(CleanableExecutor.java:246)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1426)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2034)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Sorry, acquisition timeout!
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool.handlerFromSharedCache(ConnectionPool.java:244)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:173)
        at io.agroal.pool.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.customized.QuarkusConnectionProvider.getConnection(QuarkusConnectionProvider.java:23)
        at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104)
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: Just a quick sanity check in case it helps: have you checked the configuration of *MySQL*, i.e. that it actually allows more than 20 connections from your client? You imply that you are porting an app from WildFly - are you sure it works with more than 20 connections there? Finally, the only reliable way to know is to create a small console/standalone application and actually try to open more than 20 connections to the MySQL instance you are targeting with Quarlus. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size` and `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.initial-size` properties have to be named `quarkus.datasource.max-size` and `quarkus.datasource.initial-size`, because otherwise the they apply to a named data source with the name `jdbc`, rather than to the global unnamed default data source, and I suppose you want to use that one. Your other data source properties apply to the unnamed data source. And the default `max-size` is 20, that's why you can't get over 20 connections.

Comment: Up voted as it's the reason of the issue at the time of the question. But this has changed and using prefix 'jdbc' is now the correct way for the default jdbc datasource. An additional prefix layer would be introduced before the jdbc prefix for a named jdbc datasource (in case of multiple jdbc datasources)